# Why am I getting nodata values from gdal_translate only when bounding box under a certain size? Is there a minimum bounding box size?

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate, vrt, soilgrids

## Problem: If my bounding box is too small, I get nodata

I am using gdal_translate to convert a .vrt into a .tif.

If my bounding box is large, it works perfectly. BUT as soon as I decrease the size of my bounding box under a certain invisible threshold the resulting .tif is just nodata values (and I'm sure there should be data there).

### Example:

- **WORKS**: using `boundingBox = (100000.00, 1200000.00, 500000.00,-500000.00)`(shows correct data for Nigeria-ish area.)
- **DOES NOT WORK**: using `boundingBox = (300000.00, 1200000.00, 500000.00,-500000.00)`(the whole .tif is just no-data values)

The only difference in the above boundingBoxes is the first coordinate changes from 100,000 to 300,000... reducing the width of the bounding box.

### Context:

I'm using python 3.8. Gdal version 3.2.1.
The .vrt files I am attempting to convert into .tif are from the SoilGrids webDAV.

Here is my actual code:

```
def Test(self):
        propertyType = 'phh2o'
        identifier = 'phh2o_100-200cm_Q0.05'

#        boundingBox = (100000.00, 1200000.00, 500000.00,-500000.00) #WORKS
     
        boundingBox = (300000.00, 1200000.00, 500000.00, -500000.00) # Does NOT work
        igh = "+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" 
        res = 250 
        location = "pathToHomolosineSoilGridsVRTFILE" #actual path removed
        tempVRTFile1 = "pathToTemporaryVRTFile" # actual path removed
        # create intermediate vrt files
        # first in native projection
        kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'projWin': boundingBox, 'projWinSRS': igh, 'xRes': res, 'yRes': res}
        ds = gdal.Translate(tempVRTFile1, 
                            location, 
                            **kwargs)
        outputTiffFilePath = 'pathToFinalTiffFile' # actual path removed

        # recommended by soilGrids tutorial... not using ...kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'creationOptions': ["TILED=YES", "COMPRESS=NONE", "PREDICTOR=2", "BIGTIFF=NO"] }
        kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff',
         'creationOptions': ["TILED=NO", "BIGTIFF=NO", "BLOCKYSIZE=2"] }
        ds2 = gdal.Translate(outputTiffFilePath,
            tempVRTFile1, 
            **kwargs)
       
        # ! DELETE TEMP FILES
        del ds2
        del ds
        deleteFile(tempVRTFile1)
```

Comment: Are you following this document https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/markdown/webdav_from_Python.md? And you have downloaded just the vrt file and the tif files are read from the server, right?

Comment: Yes I was following that documentation. I figured out the issue, however I hired one of the creators of GDAL as a consultant to solve it for me, so I don't feel comfortable sharing the solution here, since he did not agree to that and the solution is his intellectual property.